# Tests for asynchron functions which depend on the previous one with mochajs

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm writing a set of tests for a server.
Basically there are pre defined requests and the expected answers for every of them.

The tests are stored in a json file, so I could later extend it as demanded.

A few tests rely on two ID's of foregoing test, so the tests shouldn't be executed in parallel. To archive that I'm using the [waterfall function of the async library](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall), so im able to pass arguments to the next function.

The problem is, when I'm iterating through this array of tests, I'm calling `it(testname, function(done){...})`.In this function I execute the request and compare the response to the expected answer. After that I call the `done` function so mochajs knows the test is finished.

When I'm starting the tests, the first one get's executed, but no further ones.

For me it looks like that mochajs recognizes that there's currently no other test-task running, so it stops the script.

This is the test:

```
var testFunctions=[];

predefinedTests.forEach(function(test){
     var fn = function(error, id_1, id_2, callback){

         it("Test", function(done){
             makeAsyncRequest(test.url, function(res){
                 expect(res).to.have.properties(test.answer);
                 id_1=res.id1;
                 id_2=res.id2;
                 done();
                 /*check if it's the first test, 
                 if that's the case it needs to use the first argument as callback */
                 if(callback==undefined) return error(null, id_1, id_2);
                 callback(null, id_1, id_2);
             });
         });

     }
    testFunctions.push(fn);
});
async.waterfall(testFunctions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the tests shouldn't be executed in parallel.

Declaring a test to be asynchronous only tells Mocha that is must wait for the test to be complete, not that it is free to run tests in parallel. **Mocha does not run tests in parallel, no matter whether they are synchronous or not.** So you do not have to use `async` to prevent Mocha from doing something it does not do in the first place. (There exist packages that you must *add* to your test setup if you want tests running in parallel. Like [this one](https://github.com/danielstjules/mocha.parallel). Presumably, they patch Mocha to add the parallel capability.)

You should just remove the `async` stuff, and have your `foreEach` callback call `it` directly.

Other than this, you have set up your test suite so that one test depends on the status of a previous test. Generally, **you should write your Mocha tests so that they are independent from one another.** Mocha is really designed so that the tests are supposed to be run independently. For instance, if you use `--grep` to select only a subset of tests. Mocha won't know about the dependencies between your tests and you'll get failures if the selected tests depend on tests that were not selected. Generally, you want to put anything a test depends on in a `before` or `beforeEach` hook.

If you are in a situation where doing this would be onerous, you could keep state in a higher scope. I would not want to make it global, so I'd put everything inside a `describe`:

```
describe("all tests", function () {
    // WARNING: The following tests must be run in sequence. 
    // We have to do this because [explain here what reason requires
    // this setup].
    var id1;
    var id2;

    predefinedTests.forEach(function(test){
        it("Test", function(done){
            makeAsyncRequest(test.url, function(res){
                expect(res).to.have.properties(test.answer);
                id1=res.id1;
                id2=res.id2;
             done();
        });
    });
});
```

(I don't see in your question how the `idX` variables are used to make a new request so my code above does not show it. I presume `makeAsyncRequest` would somehow use them.)

Comment: That means I could declare two global variables for my id's and just use these in every iteration?

Comment: I see you code gets the ids from `test.id1` and `test.id2` (i.e. `id_1 = test.id1` and `id_2 = test.id2`). I also see you have `id_1` and `id_2` in the list of parameters of the functions that `async.waterfall` call, and the values are passed to the next function but I don't see this as having any effect at all. (Meaning, if in fact Mocha was able to run all your tests, the result you would get is not what you expect.)

Comment: Is it that `test.id1` and `test.id2` are *assigned* by `makeAsyncRequest`? (If so, I did not get this from your question.)

Comment: Indeed, the id's should be set by the response, I've fixed it.